# Como é o funcionamento desta classe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, ado.net

```
DataSet
OleDbConnection
OleDbCommand
OleDbDataAdapter
OleDbDataReader
```

Ainda não consegui entender essa classs em .net. Para que serve esses dataSets e etc?
Estou usando isso:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

A classe está assim:

```
public class AcessoDAL
{
public AcessoDAL()
{
}

protected static IDbConnection CriaConexaoOleDb()
{
    String sConecta = (String)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Conexao"];
    OleDbConnection conexaoOLEDB;
    conexaoOLEDB = new OleDbConnection(sConecta);
    conexaoOLEDB.Open();
    return conexaoOLEDB;
}

protected static OleDbDataReader cria_DataReader_OleDb(String sSQL, OleDbConnection conecOledb)
{
    OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand(sSQL, conecOledb);
    OleDbDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    comando.Dispose();
    return dr;
}

protected static OleDbDataReader cria_DataReader_OleDb(String sSQL)
{
    String sConecta = (String)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Conexao"];
    OleDbConnection conexaoOLEDB;
    conexaoOLEDB = new OleDbConnection(sConecta);
    conexaoOLEDB.Open();
    OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand(sSQL, conexaoOLEDB);
    OleDbDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    comando.Dispose();
    return dr;
}

protected static OleDbDataAdapter cria_DataAdapter_OleDb(String sSQL, OleDbConnection conecOledb)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conecOledb);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return da;
}

protected static DataSet cria_DataSet_OleDb(String sSQL, OleDbConnection conecOledb)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conecOledb);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}

protected static DataSet cria_DataSet_OleDb(OleDbDataAdapter da)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}

protected static OleDbCommand cria_Command_OleDb(String sSQL, OleDbConnection conecOledb)
{
    OleDbCommand comando = conecOledb.CreateCommand();
    comando.CommandText = sSQL;
    comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    return comando;
}


protected static OleDbCommand cria_Command_OleDb(String sSQL, OleDbConnection conecOledb, CommandType TipoComando)
{
    OleDbCommand comando = conecOledb.CreateCommand();
    comando.CommandText = sSQL;
    comando.CommandType = TipoComando;
    return comando;
}
```

}

Comment: Sua dúvida é relativamente genérica. Talvez valha uma visita ao site da MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Talvez eu devesse pagar um curso então. Porque eu li algumas coisas e ainda não consegui entender.

Comment: Podem negativar a pergunta a vontade não estou nem aí.

Comment: Talvez uma visita ao 'Get started' (http://www.asp.net/get-started) faça alguma diferença na tua life.

Comment: Oi Aline. Bom, a sua pergunta é justa, mas podia ser mais bem formatada. Você poderia postar, por exemplo, um pequeno trecho do restante do código onde essa classe é usada (e certamente esse trecho existe, pois essa classe deve ser algo que você encontrou em um código que está mantendo, não?). Eu não sou especialista em C#, mas essa classe me parece fornecer o acesso genérico a um banco de dados. Seu uso deve ser mais claro observando mesmo trechos de código em que ela é de fato utilizada.

Comment: Eu entendo que é frustrante receber votos negativos, mas na minha opinião você não devia "não estar nem ai". Esse tipo de comentário só vai atrair mais votos negativos e não vai te ajudar em nada. Procure editar a pergunta pra melhorá-la. :)

Comment: A pergunta é ampla demais, o problema é a classe em que aspecto? O DAL? Os conceitos de acesso a camada de dados do .net? Os comandos são relativamente simples, alguem simplesmente centralizou o comandos básicos para acesso a camada de dados. Abrir conexão, ler dados, etc. Isso em uma implementação especifica par OLE. Mesmo assim, não tem como ensinar tudo isso assim numa resposta.

Comment: Certo. Eu tenho dúvidas de tudo, não entendi nada kkkkkkkkkkk. Então vou pagar um curso de c# . net depois posso fazer uma pergunta melhor.

Comment: Sim, a classe DAL mesmo. A minha dúvida é com essa classe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que os comentários e referências utilizadas possam lhe ajudar a compreender melhor.

```
public class AcessoDAL
{
    //Construtor da classe sem parâmetros.
    //Não há necessidade desse construtor pois os seus métodos são estáticos,
    //ou seja, não precisa instanciar o objeto para acessar.
    public AcessoDAL()
    {
    }

    //Cria uma conexão com o banco de dados
    protected static IDbConnection CriaConexaoOleDb()
    {
        ///Pega a string de conexão no arquivo de configuração do sistema.
        ///Se for MVC um Web.config, se for um desktop um App.config
        String sConecta = (String)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Conexao"];
        OleDbConnection conexaoOLEDB;
        ///Cria um novo objeto para a conexão com o banco de dados
        ///com a string de conexão obtida do arquivo de configuração
        conexaoOLEDB = new OleDbConnection(sConecta);
        ///Realiza a abertura da conexão com o banco de dados
        conexaoOLEDB.Open();
        ///Retorna o objeto responsável pela conexão com o banco de dados
        return conexaoOLEDB;
    }

    //Retorna um DataReader para o comando SQL executado.
    //Utilizado com um Comando SELECT * FROM tableA
    //Referência: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx
    //            https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx
    protected static OleDbDataReader cria_DataReader_OleDb(String sSQL, OleDbConnection conecOledb)
    {
        ///Cria um novo objeto responsável por executar o camando
        ///SQL no banco de dados
        OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand(sSQL, conecOledb);
        ///Executa o comando solicitando um DAtaReader como retorno e pedindo para fechar a conexão no término.
        OleDbDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        ///Libera os recursos utilizados pelo objeto
        comando.Dispose();
        ///Retorna o objeto DataReader obtido com as informações da consulta SQL
        return dr;
    }

    //Retorna um DataReader para o comando SQL executado.
    //Uma alternativa ao método acima, sem a necessidade de passar a conexão,
    //pois a mensa é criada dentro do método.
    //Utilizado com um Comando SELECT * FROM tableA
    //Referência: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx
    //            https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx
    protected static OleDbDataReader cria_DataReader_OleDb(String sSQL)
    {
        ///Pega a string de conexão no arquivo de configuração do sistema.
        ///Se for MVC um Web.config, se for um desktop um App.config
        String sConecta = (String)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Conexao"];
        OleDbConnection conexaoOLEDB;
        ///Cria um novo objeto para a conexão com o banco de dados
        ///com a string de conexão obtida do arquivo de configuração
        conexaoOLEDB = new OleDbConnection(sConecta);
        ///Realiza a abertura da conexão com o banco de dados
        conexaoOLEDB.Open();
        ///Cria um novo objeto responsável por executar o camando
        ///SQL no banco de dados
        OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand(sSQL, conexaoOLEDB);
        ///Executa o comando solicitando um DAtaReader como retorno e pedindo para fechar a conexão no término.
        OleDbDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        ///Libera os recursos utilizados pelo objeto
        comando.Dispose();
        ///Retorna o objeto DataReader obtido com as informações da consulta SQL
        return dr;
    }

    //Cria um DataAdapter. Geralmente utilizado para preencher um DataSet
    //Referência: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx
    //            https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.common.dataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx
    protected static OleDbDataAdapter cria_DataAdapter_OleDb(String sSQL, OleDbConnection conecOledb)
    {
        ///Cria um novo DataAdapter utilizando um comando SQL e uma conexão com o bando
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conecOledb);
        ///Cria um novo objeto DataSet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ///Preenche o DataSet (Sem motivos pois o mesmo não é utilizado)
        da.Fill(ds);
        ///Retorna o DataAdapter criado
        return da;
    }

    //Cria um DataSet com as informações resultantes da consulta SQL executada
    //Referência: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx
    //            https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.common.dataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx
    protected static DataSet cria_DataSet_OleDb(String sSQL, OleDbConnection conecOledb)
    {
        ///Cria um novo DataAdapter utilizando um comando SQL e uma conexão com o bando
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conecOledb);
        ///Cria um novo objeto DataSet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ///Preenche o DataSet, agora sim com motivo
        da.Fill(ds);
        ///Retorna o DataSet
        return ds;
    }

    //Cria um DataSet utilizando o DataAdapter passado como parâmetro
    //Referência: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx
    //            https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.common.dataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx
    protected static DataSet cria_DataSet_OleDb(OleDbDataAdapter da)
    {
        ///Cria o objeto DataSet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ///Preenche o DataSet com o DataAdapter recebido
        da.Fill(ds);
        ///Retorna o DataSet preenchido
        return ds;
    }

    //Cria um objeto Command para a exeução de um comando SQL
    //Referência: http://www.macoratti.net/09/04/c_adn_3.htm
    //            https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx
    protected static OleDbCommand cria_Command_OleDb(String sSQL, OleDbConnection conecOledb)
    {
        ///Cria o objeto Command com base na conexão
        OleDbCommand comando = conecOledb.CreateCommand();
        ///Informa o comando SQL para ser executado
        comando.CommandText = sSQL;
        ///Define o tipo de comando como Text
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        ///Retorna o objeto Command
        return comando;
    }

    //Cria um objeto Command para a exeução de um comando SQL
    //Referência: http://www.macoratti.net/09/04/c_adn_3.htm
    //            https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx
    protected static OleDbCommand cria_Command_OleDb(String sSQL, OleDbConnection conecOledb, CommandType TipoComando)
    {
        ///Cria o objeto Command com base na conexão
        OleDbCommand comando = conecOledb.CreateCommand();
        ///Informa o comando SQL para ser executado
        comando.CommandText = sSQL;
        ///Define o tipo do comando de acordo com o tipo recebido por parâmetro
        comando.CommandType = TipoComando;
        ///Retorna o objeto Command
        return comando;
    }
}
```